# how to search for multiple values in one excel sheet and copy it to another sheet

Tags: excel, sqlbulkcopy

Good day

I have a huge problem

I have an online store and need to update products and prices
I have an excel sheet with all of the current products online and recieved a new pricelist
Now the problem is that Im dealing with over 5000 products and I cant update them one by one

What I need now is code to copy the prices from the one sheet and move it to the coresponding SKU/product code on the other sheet

I also have a list of the EOL products which I need to remove from the current Excel sheet
So I need a code to find the product code/SKU on the EOL sheet and then delete the whole row with the corresponding SKU on the other sheet

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your products have a unique ID that is available in all three tables, this should be an easy task that does not require any programming.

**1. Update prices**

All you need is a `VLOOKUP` formula. I assume your list with all products and prices have the product ID in column A and the (old) price in column B. I your new pricelist has the same format. Then place the following formula in cell B2 (where you currently have your old price):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,[NewPriceFile]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)
```

This will return you the new price.

**2. Delete old products**
Here I assume you simply have a list of EOL product IDs. Place the following formula in column C:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A2,[EOLFile]Sheet1!$A:$A,0))
```

This will return `FALSE` every time that the product is found in the EOL list and `TRUE` else.

Now you only need to apply an AutoFilter to the full list (*Data* tab->*Sort & Filter*->*Filter*) and filter column C for `FALSE`. Select all rows and delete them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>).

In the same way you can also check column B if all products were found. In case no product was found, `#N/A!`is shown, which you can filter. Alternatively, you can combine your formula with an `IFERROR` and use the old price if no new price was found:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,[NewPriceFile]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0),D2)
```

(This assumes that the old price is stored in D2)

Comment: Didnt have to use the Iferror, when I did the =vlookup formula, the products that were not on the new pricelist where it didn't find a price it just showed NA so I know that that product is then EOL

Comment: Just one last thing, now there are new products on the new pricelist, I want to know which are new and which not. (the new ones will not be in the old pricelist) how will I go about doing that

Comment: Figured it out, Thank you very much