# Searching & Highlighting Multiple Values

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two workbooks open, one with a master list of 4280 survey ID #s & one with a select group of about 420 survey ID #s (called "DNAs").

The master list includes all of the DNA survey IDs. I would like to search for the DNA survey IDs in the master list to highlight them and add this DNA code. Is there a way to do this all at once instead of individually?

When I used different formulas given in other answers, I did not get what I needed. Here is a similar situation to mine:

[how to search for multiple values in one excel sheet and copy it to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939352/how-to-search-for-multiple-values-in-one-excel-sheet-and-copy-it-to-another-shee/24495855#24495855)

Comment: I think I may need a formula-- this observation is solely based off what I read in that other person's problem that I quoted though...

Comment: Do you know what the exact formula would be and where I would copy & paste it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this conceptually is what you want. You can replace with your cell references, etc. The formula in the formula bar is in cell F1. The final parameter (0) of the MATCH function tells it to look for that exact value. The ISERROR function will return TRUE if the value is successfully found in the other workbook. The conditional formatting rule in the screenshot is applied to range $E$1:$E$9.

---

[image: Conditional Formatting Based on Match]

Answer (score 0):

I found the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430130/create-macro-to-search-worksheet-for-list-of-strings-and-highlight-the-row) to be quite useful when I was attempting something similar and It worked great.  I coulnd't find my old example that pertained to my particular problem but if you do any VBA you should be able to tweak it to your needs.  Best I could provide.  Good luck.